# Using NLTK or similar, how in Python can I conjugate verb once I have the base word (lemma)?

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet

Using NLTK or similar, how can I take a base word (lemma) and get other parts of speech for that word, especially other forms of a verb?

NLTK does not directly support this.

I tried "pattern" with Python 3.9 and 3.10 and could not get it working.
NodeBox and MontyLingua just lead to dead links these days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.